# Manual implementation of OpenCV Sobel function

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing

[image: My image]

If I have an image and call the OpenCV Sobel function with

```
Sobel(Img,gradX,CV_16S,1,0,3);
convertScaleAbs(gradX,absGradX);
imshow("Gradient Image",absGradX);
```

I get a nice gradient image

I would like to use filter2D with a custom kernel to calculate my x gradient. My sobel kernel is
1 0 -1
2 0 -2
1 0 -1
now when I try this I am getting just an all black image

```
float  xVals[9] = {.125,0,-.125,.25,0,-.25,.125,0,-.125};
Mat xKernel = Mat(3,3,CV_32F,xVals);
Mat gradXManual,absGradXManual;
filter2D(Img,gradXManual,-1,xKernel,Point(-1,-1),0,BORDER_DEFAULT);
convertScaleAbs(gradXManual,absGradXManual);
imshow("Manual Gradient",absGradXManual);
```

Resulting gradient image is all black. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: Using your custom kernel, I get an output.  Can you place what image you're using here?  However, I'm using Python OpenCV, but the way to invoke the functions is practically the same as the C++ version.  I used a test image I have and I get an output from both Sobel and your custom kernel.

Comment: Interesting, I did not get anything with the custom kernel. I've edited my post to include the image I used.

Comment: I'll check now.  Give me one moment.

Comment: The main difference I see between the Sobel implementation and your gradient is the fact that you took the Sobel kernel by divided each element by 8.  As such, any gradients you detect, you'll get a contrast reduction and that's what I see.  Actually, you are basically taking the gradient result and dividing by 8 and so you are reducing the intensities of the output by a factor of 8.  Try doing: `float xVals[9] = {1f,0f,-1f,2f,0f,-2f,1f,0f,-1f};` the **actual** Sobel kernel, then run your code again.  You should see a higher boost in contrast.

Comment: Ah, you are right. I was normalizing which was reducing contrast too much. Thanks!

Comment: The reason why is because when you're displaying your image, any negative values will be truncated to 0.  As such, try adding 128 to every pixel in the gradient and you should be able to capture the negative gradients.

Comment: In case anyone is interested the filter2D function call should be       filter2D(blurredImg,gradXManual,CV_16S,xKernel,Point(-1,-1),0,BORDER_DEFAULT);  (substituted the CV_16S for the -1 as the 3rd parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually got an output from the custom kernel that you have created.  I used Python OpenCV to do this, but the way of calling the functions in OpenCV are pretty much the same.  To be self-contained, this is the Python code I called for your image using the Sobel and your custom kernel:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
im = cv2.imread('Nj9fM.png'); #// Save image to computer first

#// Call using built-in Sobel
out1 = cv2.Sobel(im, cv2.CV_16S, 0, 1, 3)
out1 = cv2.convertScaleAbs(out1.copy())

#// Create custom kernel
xVals = np.array([0.125,0,-0.125,0.25,0,-0.25,0.125,0,-0.125]).reshape(3,3)

#// Call filter2D
out2 = cv2.filter2D(im, cv2.CV_32F, xVals, None, (-1,-1), 0, cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
out2 = cv2.convertScaleAbs(out2.copy())

cv2.imshow('Output 1', out1)
cv2.imshow('Output 2', out2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

In terms of C++:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Mat im = imread("Nj9fM.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); // Save image to computer first

    // Call using built-in Sobel
    Mat out1, out2;
    Sobel(img, out1, CV_16S, 1, 0, 3);
    convertScaleAbs(out1, out2);

    // Create custom kernel
    Mat xVals = Mat_<float>(3, 3) << 0.125, 0, -0.125, 0.25, 0, -0.25, 0.125, 0, -0.125;

    // Call filter2D
    filter2D(im, out2, -1, xVals, Point(-1,-1), 0 ,BORDER_DEFAULT);
    convertScaleAbs(out2, out2);

    imshow("Output 1", out1);
    imshow("Output 2", out1);
    waitKey(0);
    destroyWindow("Output 1");
    destroyWindow("Output 2");
}
```

If you run this code, you'll actually see both images where the first one uses the built-in Sobel, while the other one uses your custom kernel.  The main difference I see between the Sobel implementation and your gradient is the fact that you took the Sobel kernel by divided each element by 8. As such, any gradients you detect, you'll get a contrast reduction and that's what I see. Actually, you are basically taking the gradient result and dividing by 8 and so you are reducing the intensities of the output by a factor of 8. Try doing: `float xVals2[9] = {1f,0f,-1f,2f,0f,-2f,1f,0f,-1f};` the actual Sobel kernel, then run your code again. You should see a higher boost in contrast.  For Python, this would be:

```
xVals2 = np.array([1.,0.,-1.,2.,0,-2.,1.,0,-1.]).reshape(3,3)
```

Also in C++:

```
Mat xVals2 = Mat_<float>(3, 3) << 1f, 0f, -1f, 2f, 0f, -2f, 1f, 0f, -1f;
```

If you run your code using this kernel, you'll see that there's a higher contrast.  You'll see that there is more noise though, as the gradient values are larger.

Comment: By dividing the Sobel kernel by 8 you get correct estimates of the derivative.